# PHP - Textlink to link error

Tags: php, regex

I want to convert textlinks to "real" links using php.

My problem is, that also images get changed - anyone knows how I can fix it?

```html
Some text with link - the first (Image) should stay as it is, the others should be converted

<img src="http://www.google.de/someimage.jpg">
www.google.de
http://www.google.de
```

The script I use

```
    $text = preg_replace(
                array(
                    '/(?(?=<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)(?:<a[^>]*>.+<\/a>)|([^="\']?)(\b(?:https?|ftp|bf2|):\/\/[^<> \n\r]+))/iex',
                    '/<a([^>]*)target="?[^"\']+"?/i',
                    '/<a([^>]+)>/i',
                    '/(^|\s)(www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex'),
                array(
                    "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))",
                    '<a\\1',
                    '<a\\1 target="_blank">',
                    "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))",
                ),
                $text
            );
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse/modify html - use XML parsers.  Parse the document, then iterate over nodes and only apply the change to the text nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your preg_replace arrays:

- Line 1: causes the problem with `<img src="">` links but was working properly for links starting with http://.
- Lines 2 and 3: had no effect on your sample code with google.de links.
- Line 4: works properly for links starting with www.

Adapting your Line 4 you can use a similar regular expression for the http links:

```
$text = preg_replace( 
  array( 
    '/(^|\s)(http:\/\/www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex',
    '/(^|\s)(www.[^<> \n\r]+)/iex'
  ), array(
    "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))",
    "stripslashes((strlen('\\2')>0?'\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\">\\2</a>\\3':'\\0'))"
  ),
  $text
);
```